# What is the right workflow of merging in git with BitBucket

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

What is the right workflow of merging in git with BitBucket

As I recently got into trubles (not only once) I would like to know what is the right way of merging in git ...

When I start with developing a feature I create a branch from the master .
During some time there are commits into my feature branch and also in the master branch - even on the same files.
Now the feature is compleate and I want to merge it back to the master -> what is the right way to do this?

When I simply push my changes to the remote (BitBucket) repository and than create the Pull request I get some Merge Conflict.
How to resolve them?

A)
1: checkout the feature branch
2: merge remote master branch into the feature branch
3: push to remote (here I get into my push also all the stuff from the master)
4: create pull request
When I do this with my IntelliJ Idea GUI I don't get any merge confilcts (on merging to master local), but in BitBucket I do get them.

even simple like this:

```
<<<<<<<
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
=======
>>>>>>>
```

B)
1: checkout the feature branch
2: rebase onto the remote master branch
3: push to remote
4: create pull request

When I do this with my IntelliJ Idea GUI, in bitbucket in the pull-request it seems that the code to merge contains changes that are not from me - but part of the changes from the master.

What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be forgetting to `git fetch`. While your local git repo will track remote branches, it doesn't sync up with them automatically. You must use `fetch` or `pull`.

In general, it's much easier to work within your local repo rather than mixing and matching with local and remote branches. Try doing the following:

1. Checkout master (local)
2. `git pull` to get the latest changes
3. Checkout issue branch (local)
4. `git merge master` or `git rebase master` (pros and cons to each...)
5. `git push` (with merge) or `git push --force-with-lease` (with rebase)